# encounter in animation a mouse over and mouse out in nested timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

problem when i mouse over or mouse out using actionscript 3 to my button it keeps on repeating and not finishing the animation or worse the animation or the object is not showing. ive put on labels for guide to where the animation is if you mouse_over the button or mouse out, ive also put a stop action

here is my code

```
stop();

import flash.events.Event;

btn1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, casinoHome);
function casinoHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip(this.root).btn1_mc.gotoAndPlay("rover");
MovieClip(this.root).outline1_mc.gotoAndPlay("roveroutline");
}

btn1_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, casinoHome2);
function casinoHome2 (e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip(this.root).btn1_mc.gotoAndPlay("mouseout");
MovieClip(this.root).outline1_mc.gotoAndPlay("mouseoutine");
}

btn2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, sportsHome);
function sportsHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip(this.root).btn2_mc.gotoAndPlay("rover2");
}

btn2_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, sportsHome2);
function sportsHome2 (e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip(this.root).btn2_mc.gotoAndPlay("mouseout2");
}

btn3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, slotHome);
function slotHome (e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip(this.root).btn3_mc.gotoAndPlay("rover3");
}

btn3_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, slotHome2);
function slotHome2 (e:MouseEvent):void{
MovieClip(this.root).btn3_mc.gotoAndPlay("mouseout3");
}
```

Comment: Do you have an animation after the "rover" frame? If yes, write `stop()` at the end of an animation. Can you provide FLA file? I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have put a `stop();` action at the end of each animation.

example:

btn1_mc:

[image]

outline1_mc:

[image]